# What are the differences between the two Underscore.js syntaxes?

Tags: coding-style, underscore.js

With [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) you can write code like this:

```
_.each([1,2,3], callback)
```

...or like this:

```
_([1,2,3]).each(callback)
```

Are there any differences I should be aware of?

For example: Is there any difference in performance? Are there any 'philosophical' differences between the two approaches? Is there a reason why the Underscore documentation uses the first style, or did they just pick one for consistency?

Comment: Probably that the second is like Ruby and arguably a more object-oriented approach while the first is definitely more procedural in origin.

Comment: Could one of the people who closed this please explain a bit more about why? Are all "advantages and disadvantages of..." questions (of which there are many) disallowed? If not, then what is wrong with this one specifically?

Comment: @callum I don't know much about Underscore.js, but perhaps the reason this question was deemed no constructive is that there's no significant difference -- some people prefer one and some prefer the other. Rather than asking in the abstract, it might help to ask about the specific problem that inspired you to ask the question in the first place.

Comment: If the answer is that there is no significant difference, then that's useful information. It means I can choose based on personal preference and I don't have to worry about performance or other technical issues. I don't see how this means the question is 'not constructive'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The very document you linked](http://underscorejs.org/) in your question says, in [the section on chaining](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining):

> You can use Underscore in either an object-oriented or a functional
>   style, depending on your preference. The following two lines of code
>   are identical ways to double a list of numbers.

So, the two styles are equivalent, and you should pick whichever style suits you.